# Knockout.js binding in <html>

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.2

I'm trying to add a binding in the `<html>` element of the site and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there any restriction applying bindings in elements outside the body element?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-bind="css: {'visible-menu' : $root.panels.visibleMenu }">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`applyBindings` [defaults to using `<body>`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/281e195eeae633d5f62f2fe08a8790506682bbb1/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L446) if you don't pass a root node:

```
rootNode = rootNode || window.document.body; // Make "rootNode" parameter optional
```

If you pass the `<html>` node, it should work as expected.  One way to do this, if you're using jQuery, is to use [the `:root` selector](https://api.jquery.com/root-selector/):

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $(':root').get(0));
```

Or by tag name:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]);
```

Comment: Do you know if this makes the site more vulnerable in some way?